# Understanding how std::forward overloads work

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, forward

I want to doublecheck that I have correct understanding on how forward overloads work

```
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( std::remove_reference_t<T>& t ) noexcept;

template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( std::remove_reference_t<T>&& t ) noexcept;
```

If we call the forward with some local variable `n`, say it's `int`, overloads will be specified as

```
  constexpr int&& forward( int& t ) noexcept;   
  constexpr int&& forward( int&& t ) noexcept;
```

So the first one will be chosen for our case. If we call forward with just `4` overloads will be specified same, but second version will be chosen. So first overload always catch all lvalues, and second all rvalues. Correct?

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. I recommend using https://cppinsights.io/.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Almost.  You can't just call `forward`.

If you call `foward` with a local variable `n` such as `int`:

```
int n;
forward(n);
```

you get a compilation error.  If you call `forward<int>`:

```
int n;
forward<int>(n);
```

you get two overload candidates:

```
constexpr int&& forward<int>(int& t)noexcept;
constexpr int&& forward<int>(int&& t)noexcept;
```

then normal overload resolution runs, and selects the first.

If we do

```
forward(4);
```

again, compilation error, as `T` cannot be deduced, but if we do

```
forward<int>(4);
```

two overloads are selected between:

```
constexpr int&& forward<int>(int& t)noexcept;
constexpr int&& forward<int>(int&& t)noexcept;
```

of which the 2nd is selected.

Things get slighly more intersting when we do

```
int n;
forward<int&>(n);
```

we get

```
constexpr int& forward<int&>(int& t)noexcept;
constexpr int& forward<int&>(int&& t)noexcept;
```

the return value changes from `int&&` to `int&`, but the arguments don't.

The remove reference on the arguments both blocks deducting the template parameter and ensures that reference collapsing never turns them into lvalue references.

So the first one is always an lvalue reference, the second is always an rvalue reference.

But to be clear, you can't just call `forward` -- you must call `forward<T>` for some type `T`, and that type `T` changes what the overloads look like.  In all (almost?) reasonable uses of `forward` this doesn't matter, but unreasonable uses could make a difference.

```
struct unreasonable {
  operator int&&()&;
};
unreasonable r;
forward<int>(r);
```

that will select the 2nd overload.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I've also checked, expectedly there is error if to call forward<int&>(8); But can you please explain more your unreasonable example?  Whta is last ampersand in operator int&&()&;?